# nextjs project consuming lot of server memory

Tags: node.js, next.js

we have a nextjs project. It's a builder project and web pages loads from json data and user works from builder and dasshboard. not much users. There are always 2-15 users working in dashboard continuously and some extra users. But we see the pm2 process is getting filled with 2gb, 3gb of ram. We are using 32gb ram and 16 cpu. We are using all of them in cluster mood. How to know why and which function or page taking all the memory and to keep it low?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a reported bug in NextJS since version 13.3.5, which also affects the "stable" 13.4 App Router release of NextJS. It makes the memory use very high. Currently the best solution is to downgrade to 13.3.4.
See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49929